# Are there good bounds for $\prod_{n=1}^m (1+a_n)$ when $\sum a_n$ diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product, upper-lower-bounds

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of nonegative real numbers. In [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product) from wikipedia as well in some question here on Math SE we see that

$$1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\leq\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)\leq\exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right).$$

Now suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ diverges so that every term of the inequality above is $\infty$. For example for $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda}{n}$ with $\lambda>1$.

> My question is if there are good upper and lower bounds for
>   $\prod_{n=1}^m (1+a_n)$, $m\in\Bbb N$.

ps.: I don't care if the bounds are ugly as hell.

Comment: $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ is trivially the best bound, so you have to specify what kind of bound you are looking for. – Are you looking for bounds of the form $F\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\right)$?

Comment: I fully agree with @MartinR. Maybe telling the motivation why you need a better bound would be helpful. For example, if you want to prove a result which would require a better  bound, then tell what is the result that you want to prove.

Comment: Thank you @MartinR and Shashi for the help. I agree that I wouldn't get an answer for my problem with the old question. Now I think it is more precise.

Comment: @Shashi The result should be to find a sequence $(a_n)$ such that some thechnical properties are satisfied. A bound for a general sequence $(a_n)$ would help me to test some examples. Even if there are some good bounds just for the case $a_n=\lambda / n$ I would be happy.

Comment: Do you mean a bound in terms of $m$? Because in that case you have $$\prod_{n\leq m}(1+\lambda/n)\leq \exp(\sum_{n\leq m} \frac{\lambda}{n})\leq\exp(\lambda(\log m-\log 2+1))=c_\lambda m^\lambda$$

Comment: @JulianMejia Yes but this is a very bad upper bound. If I am not wrong, with this upper bound together with an analogously obtained lower bound, the size of the interval in which $\prod(1+\lambda / m)$ lies grows to infinity considerably fast...